# build rpm without compiling the source file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying a sample rpm package with single file.

In my source folder I have python_test_rpm.tar.gz which contains only one python script file. But, the file is not a valid python script.

All I want to do is package this and deploy it in a specific folder. While executing the rpm build command it is showing the compilation/syntax error in the python script. How to skip this validation and make the build.

> **rpmbuild command**
>   rpmbuild -v -bb
>
> **Spec File:**
>
> Name:           python_test_rpm
>
> Version:        1
>
> Release:        1
>
> Summary:        Sample RPM for Linux Installer
>
> Group:                  Development/Tools
>
> License:        GPL
>
> URL:    None
>
> Source:         python_test_rpm.tar.gz
>
> BuildRoot:         /home/rpmdev/rpmbuild
>
> %description
>
> POC package for Linux RPM installer
>
> %prep
>
> %setup -n "python_test_rpm"
>
> %install
>
> rm -rf "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
>
> mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/python_test_rpm"
>
> cp -R _mock_backport.py "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/python_test_rpm"
>
> %files
>
> /python_test_rpm/_mock_backport.py
>
> **Error Message:**
>   Compiling
>   /home/rpmdev/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/python_test_rpm-1-1.x86_64/python_test_rpm/_mock_backport.py
>   ... SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function
>   '_set_signature' it contains a nested function with free variables
>   (_mock_backport.py, line 191)
>
> error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4gSvIa (%install)
>
> RPM build errors:
>       Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4gSvIa (%install)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easy fix: Adding "exit 0' at the end of %install will disable build root policy scripts that are trying to generate %.pyo/%.pyc files.

Better fixes include overriding the specific build root policy script that is compiling python files, or simply fixing/commenting the code that does not compile.