# Creating RPM on Python 2 works, but Python 3 fails because of sys.implementation.cache_tag

Tags: python-3.x, rpm, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to create an RPM from my Python application on SLES12 SP2. This is my setup.py file:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='MyApp',
                 version='1.2.3',
                 options={'bdist_rpm': {'post_install': 'post_install.sh',
                                        'post_uninstall': 'post_uninstall.sh'}})
```

Nothing special.

Running `python setup.py bdist_rpm` works. However, running `python3 setup.py bdist_rpm` does the following:

```
running bdist_rpm
running egg_info
writing top-level names to MyApp.egg-info/top_level.txt

...

byte-compiling /home/pedro/MyApp/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/MyApp-1.2.3-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MyApp/my_file.py to my_file.cpython-34.pyc

...

Processing files: MyApp-1.2.3-1.noarch
error: File not found: /home/pedro/MyApp/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/MyApp-1.2.3-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MyApp/my_file.py

RPM build errors:
    File not found: /home/pedro/MyApp/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/MyApp-1.2.3-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MyApp/my_file.py
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

The problem appears to be that setuptools is generating a file that ends in `.cpython-34.pyc`, and later looks for a file without the `.cpython-34` but can't find it.

The RPM generation process on Python 3 goes through `distutils.util.byte_compile()`, which in turn calls `importlib.util.cache_from_source(path)`, where `path` is the file to be byte-compiled. `cache_from_source()` looks like this (abbreviated):

```
def cache_from_source(path, debug_override=None, *, optimization=None):
    path = _os.fspath(path)
    head, tail = _path_split(path)
    base, sep, rest = tail.rpartition('.')
    tag = sys.implementation.cache_tag
    if tag is None:
        raise NotImplementedError('sys.implementation.cache_tag is None')
    almost_filename = ''.join([(base if base else rest), sep, tag])
    optimization = str(optimization)
    if optimization != '':
        almost_filename = '{}.{}{}'.format(almost_filename, _OPT, optimization)
    return _path_join(head, _PYCACHE, almost_filename + BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[0])
```

The value of `sys.implementation.cache_tag` is `'cpython-34'`. This attribute of `sys` does not exist in Python 2. So it looks like `setuptools` injects this tag into the filename during byte compilation, but later forgets that it modified the filename and fails because it's looking for the original name.

How can I:

1. Disable byte-compilation during the RPM generation,
2. Disable the use of the cache tag in the byte-compilation, or
3. Make `setuptools` (or `rpmbuild`; not sure which one is searching for the original filename) be consistent in the filename it searches for?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802045/build-rpm-without-compiling-the-source-file) suggests disabling the byte-compilation altogether in the spec file, but I am looking for a way to generate the RPM with just the straight `python3 setup.py bdist_rpm --maybe-some-other-parameters` command.